# Как в htacess установить файл основным (типа index.php), если его имя меняется?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть директория на сервере, а в ней файл генерируется:

```
wp-cache-8cb538e7e7b00e4eaf2dc8b78eab7bf3.php
```

Начало всегда **wp-cache-**, а продолжение имени файла различно.

Как мне в *htacess* прописать, чтобy его подхватывал и устанавливал в качестве основного (index)?

Пробовал так: `DirectoryIndex wp-cache-*.php`, но не работает.

Comment: А Вы уверенны что Вам это нужно?
В смысле в чем смысл кэш сессии пользователя вот так подтягивать? Если Вы более обширно опишите задачу которую хотите решить - возможно Вам подскажут более грамотное решение.

Comment: Зачем подтягивать кеш как точку входа? Не понятно, обычно делают точку входа, а на ней уже манипулируют данными, к примеру созданный кеш можно подключить в виде `require (include)` конструкцией с проверкой новой даты создания или изменения файла. Подключать только актуальный файл. Не?

Comment: Беру сгенерированный кеш с локального сервера  и заливаю на хостинг. Не хочу каждый раз переименовывать файл.

Comment: Что делать серверу, если таких файлов несколько?

Comment: @vp_arth, взять последний по дате создания ;)

Comment: Файл с таким начальным именем всегда один. Кеш на самом локальном сервере обновляется. Если быть точным, то это RSS лента, которая сохраняется таким образом через плагин WP Super Cache в WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
$caches = glob('wp-cache-*.php', GLOB_NOSORT);
usort($caches, function($a, $b) {
    return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});
$caches = $caches[0];
//require_once $caches;
echo $caches,
date('d.m.Y H:i:s', filemtime($caches));
```

> wp-cache-8cb538e7e7b00e4eaf2dc8b78eab7bf3.php
>   03.11.2017 11:11:31